# getting an error msg while using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, facebook, x-cart

I am getting an warning messsage like this

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: stream does not support seeking

this is the code

```
$f=file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?message='.$facebook_message1[0].'%20'.$facebook_message1[1].'%20'.$facebook_message1[2].'%20'.$facebook_message1[3].'%20'.$facebook_message1[4].'%20'.$facebook_message1[5].'%20'.$facebook_message1[6].'%20'.$facebook_message1[7].'%20'.$facebook_message1[8].'%20'.$facebook_message1[9].'%20'.$facebook_message1[10].'%20'.$facebook_message1[11].'%20'.$facebook_message1[12].'%20'.$facebook_message1[13].'%20'.$facebook_message1[14].'%20'.$facebook_message1[15].'%20'.$facebook_message1[16].'%20'.$facebook_message1[17].'%20'.$facebook_message1[18].'%20'.$facebook_message1[19].'%20'.$facebook_message1[20].'&attachment={"name":"'.$url.'","href":"'.$url.'","caption":"","description":"","media":[{"type":"image","src":"'.$facebook_image.'","href":"'.$cat.'"}]}&uid='.$user_id.'&access_token='.$access_token.'', NULL, NULL, 246);

$fID = substr_replace($f,"",-27);
```

Comment: Holy concatenation, batman... that code is BUTT UGLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you are using the fourth parameter of `file_get_contents`. You should simply omit that and cut off the relevant part of `$f` with `substr` later, like this:

```
$f = substr($f, 246);
```

However, there are many other issues:

1. The handling of `$facebook_message` is atrocious. Save your sanity and use `implode('%20', $facebook_message)` instead of the manual string concatenation.
2. It's a really bad idea to use the magic numbers `246` and `-27` in your code. How did you produce these values? Obviously they refer to a part of the result string delimited by something, so *document that by writing code that finds the delimiters*. Your current code will break the moment facebook does any small change to their return value format, even if that change is purely technical and makes no difference from a semantic point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You've told file_get_contents to seek to offset 246 with that final argument - you cannot do this with HTTP urls. You'll have fetch the entire response, then use

```
$f = substr($f, 246);
```

to extract the portions from 246 onwards.

Comment: I've done that often with remote URLs until one project where it failed. After seeing this answer, I checked the documentation and you are right -- the documentation actually says that it sometimes works but isn't reliable. In my case I want to read the data in chunks to keep memory usage low, so I switched to fgets, which worked fine.